# Troubles with plotting

Tags: plotting

This is my code to plot a function:

```
Clear[f, plot, reg];
f[x_] = Exp[1/x] (4 x + 3);
plot = Plot[{f[x]}, {x, -2, 4}, PlotStyle -> {Darker@Cyan}, 
AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {-1, 4}, 
PlotLegends -> 
Placed[
 SwatchLegend[{Darker[Cyan]}, {Style[Exp[1/x] (4 x + 3), 
    Darker[Cyan], Bold]}, LegendMarkerSize -> {15, 15}], {0.2, 
  0.8}], AxesLabel -> {x, y}];
Show[plot, PlotRange -> {-4, 4}, AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[{0.05}], 
Axes -> True, Frame -> False, 
 GridLines -> {{{{Thick, AbsoluteDashing[{3, 3}]}}}, None}]
```

And this is the resulting plot:

[image]

I don't understand why the y axis is coloured. I don't understand why there is no x-positive region.

Comment: Should be `GridLinesStyle -> {{{{Thick, AbsoluteDashing[{3, 3}]}}}, None}`.

Comment: Why the extra `Show` command? If you put all the options in the `Plot` command, the x-positive region is included.

Comment: @herbertfederer Tried, changed nothing

Comment: @GustavoDelfino Meh, tried to modify it and nothing changed

Comment: `Minimize[{f[x], x > 0}, x]` shows that the function is outside of the designated plot range for `x > 0`

Comment: @BobHanlon Ok, but that doesn't solve my problems. Nothing changed, even if I change the PlotRange

Comment: Edit your question to show what you are trying now (revised `PlotRange`) and the result that you now get.

Comment: @BobHanlon I don't know it it makes sense to post many pics which are the same despite the change. What I did is changing the plotrange like (-2, 40) or (-1, 20) et cetera. Nothing changed

Comment: Apparently, we are getting different results than you are. We cannot propose a reason for the difference unless you post the exact code that you are currently using.

Comment: Bad form to define an option (e.g., PlotRange) in a variable `plot` *AND* in `Show`...as a starter.

Comment: *I don't understand why the y axis is coloured.* Because that’s the plot line.

Answer (score 5):

There is singularity/discontinuity at `x=0`. Limit from left is `0` and from right is `∞`. When `f[x]` is used inside `Plot` no exclusions are applied at `x=0` but when explicit function `Exp[1/x] (4 x + 3)` is used inside `Plot` exclusions are applied at `x=0`.

Why is it so is not clear to me, but you can always use option `Exclusions` to define what should be excluded from plot.

```
f[x_] = Exp[1/x] (4 x + 3);
Plot[f[x], {x, -2, 4}, PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[5]]
Plot[Exp[1/x] (4 x + 3), {x, -2, 4}, PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[5]]

Plot[f[x], {x, -2, 4}, PlotStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[5], 
 Exclusions -> 0]
```

[image]

Instead of `Exclusions -> 0` also `Exclusions -> "Singularities"`, `Exclusions -> "Discontinuities"`, `Exclusions -> All` should work, but they all failed for some reason if `f[x]` is used inside `Plot` and I consider it to be a bug of Mathematica.

Answer (score 3):

Avoiding all the conflicting needless double definitions, `Show`, useless `Frames ->False`, `reg`, `{ }`, `Axes ->True`, `GridLinesStyle`, etc.:

```
 Plot[Exp[1/x] (4 x + 3),
 {x, -2, 4},
 PlotStyle -> (dc = Darker[Cyan]),
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 AxesStyle -> Arrowheads[0.05],
 AxesLabel -> {x, y},
 PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 4}, {-4, 4}},
 PlotLegends -> 
 Placed[SwatchLegend[{dc}, {Style[Exp[1/x] (4 x + 3), dc, Bold]}, 
    LegendMarkerSize -> {15, 15}], {0.2, 0.8}]]
```

Also, you apparently don't realize how large your function is for $x>0$.

Try `PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 4}, {-4, 40}},` to see...

This also explains why your original graph goes to infinity in the region $x = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

To see what is wrong, simply try:

```
Plot[{f[x]}, {x, -2, 4}]
```

[image]

Comment: Ummm.... why the brackets around `f[x]`?

Comment: Bracket is not necessary and can be deleted.